# Rewriting an uncurried function haskell

Tags: function, haskell, tuples

I've been learning about uncurrying and applying $ in functions in haskell but I'm still having issues converting an uncurried function to something less mysterious.

The function I'm given is

```
apple = map $ uncurry $ flip ($)
```

and I realize that this takes a list of tuples and applies to corresponding function in the tuple to the variable inside. So I'm trying to rewrite it as

```
apple ls = foldr function _ ls
    where function (a,b) c = (uncurry b) (a,c)
```

I get the error for _ as a parse error and I have no idea which starting point to use. I need to make this polymorphic and I'm realizing that this most likely will not be the way to make it less mysterious. Any ideas? They'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: The original `apple`'s primary definition is based on `map` (which makes sense, as it takes a list and "does something" to each element of the list to give you a list of results). So the most straightforward way to reimplement it is to use `map`, not `foldr`. You *can* use `foldr`, because `foldr` is more general and can be used to implement `map`. But in any `foldr` based solution to this problem you basically *have* to include a reimplementation of `map`, which adds more complexity and doesn't help you make it clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple has the type

```
apple :: [(a, a->b)] -> [b]
```

We could rewrite it as

```
apple ls = map (\(a, f) -> f a) ls
```

So writing this with `foldr` is very doable,

```
apple ls = foldr (\(a, f) rest -> f a : rest) [] ls
```

Or, we can rewrite this to pointfree

```
apple = foldr ( (:) . (uncurry . flip $ ($)) ) []
```

The reason for the parse error is that `_` is the special syntax for "variables I don't care about". This let's you write things like

```
 foo _ _ _ _ a = a
```

And not get an error about repeated variables. Basically we just filled in `_` with the starting empty list and fixed `function` so that it appends to `c` rather than trying to apply it to `a`.

If I wanted to write this in the clearest way possible, then the original

```
apple = map . uncurry . flip $ ($)
```

Is quite nice.

Comment: Your first type signature shall be `apple :: [(a, a->b)] -> [b]`, shall it?

Comment: Even though it's not point free, I'd say the clearest definition is actually: `apple xfs = [f x | (x, f) <- xfs]`  Shorter and much clearer than any of the others.

Comment: @NeilBrown But he asks for "uncurring", and your version do not using it at all!

Answer (score 1):

The key for understanding is removing complexity.

Thus I would suggest you deal with a single tuple first. Write the following function:

```
 tapp :: (a, a ->b) -> b
```

in terms of ($) and `flip` and `uncurry`.
(To make it even easier, you could first do it for a tuple `(a -> b, a)` first).

Next, make clear to yourself how map works: If you have a function `f :: (a -> b)`, then `map f` will be a function `[a] -> [b]`. Hence `map tapp` does what you want.

You can now replace `tapp` in `map (tapp)` by it's definition (this are the benefits of referential transparency).
And this should take you back to your original expression. More or less so, because, for example:

```
f $ g h
```

can be written

```
f (g h)
```

or

```
(f . g) h
```